# Disable Ajax validation during a POST request LARAVEL

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

[image]I'm trying to pass an array of elements from jQuery to PHP Laravel. I'm in a projects update detail.
Everybody is using ajax to make a post request. It's working, but it gets stuck every time cause it needs to validate all the fields in that page before going on, but PHP is already doing that... I need Ajax just to pass that array to PHP, I don't need it doing the same thing PHP is doing. So I want to skip all the validation rules in ajax.

Do you have any idea ?

this is my code

```
var token = $('input[name=_token]').val()

$.ajax({
    data: {_token: token, dataOrder: orderArray},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/admin/projects/update/37',
    error: function(data) {
        instance
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log('server errors',errors);
   },
   success: function (data) {
        $(".content").append('<strong>Yeah</strong>');
   }
```

});

With this code I always get the 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

this is my controller core code

```
public function update(Request $data)
    {

    $this->validate($data, [

        'title' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:projects,title,' . $data->id,
        'slug' =>'min:3|max:255|unique:projects,slug,' . $data->id,
        'date' => 'required|before:now',
        'client' => 'min:3|max:255',
        'category' => 'required',
        'image_list' => 'image|max:2000',
        'description' => 'required|min:3'

    ]);

    $update = Project::find($data->id);
    $update->title = $data->title;
    $update->slug = $this->slug($data, $data->slug);
    $update->date = $data->date;
    $update->client = $data->client;
    $update->category_id = $data->category;
    $update->description = $data->description;

    $update->save();
}
```

screenshot of a dd($data->all());
[image]

Comment: How do you build orderArray? Is that serialized data?

Comment: orderArray is an associative array formed by IDs of pics as KEY and a simple increasing loop as VALUE. I'm using jQuery UI sortable and that keeps trace of the new position af a moved element. Every time that I change position of a pic the orderArray will have a higher or lower loop number associated to the pic ID.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: [jQuery Post Ajax call](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

The simplest Ajax call using jQuery without validation:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://your.url.com",
  data: {your: data},
  success: function() { // Executes on successful call },
});
```

Comment: I posted my current code. with that code I always get "422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Comment: Have you checked that project with ID 37 really exists? Also, in an update ajax call, the `_token` variable should be `{!! csrf_token() !!}`...

Comment: yes ID 37 is a test page that I'm using. About the csrf_token I saw many solutions, now I'm getting the value of it from the hidden field and sending  it as a part of my data. Earlier I used to get other errors when I wasn't including it properly but with this way, it seems working... but I don't know so much ... How can I include it using your way ? where Do I need to paste the {!! csrf_token() !!} ?

Comment: `{!! csrf_token() !!}` contains the correct token only in case you are making the Ajax call inside a Blade template file...

Answer (score 0):

Have a CSRF token on your HTML page.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In the script use ajaxSetup method to set the x-csrf-token header.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

..and remove the _token bit form your data {} object.

Comment: I don't have that metatag on my update page. the CSFR token is added as an input type hidden, by the Laravel form builder, within my update form.

Comment: Try disabling any javascript actions on that page and submit to check whether it has to do with ajax request or something else is wrong with server code

Comment: if I disable the Ajax the submit works correctly. It validates the fields and submits it. The point is that I only need to pass an array to PHP and I only saw that an ajax request can do that... but when I use ajax it wants to validate every field so I should pass it every value of any required fields in the "data"

Comment: Also how is your script validating dataOrder array

Comment: Try this out.. Create a new route, and dd the $request and check if it shows the data you posted.

Comment: I have added the token on my header and now using jQuerySetup, that is working fine. But now I went back to the original error... I attached a screenshot on my post... that is what I get if I don't include in the data ajax request all the values of the required fields

Comment: I need to se how you're trying to access and process that data at the backend

Comment: do dd($request->all()) in your script that should be enough to debug the rest

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I had errors regarding the Laravel form validation in my Ajax call was because the Ajax call was made inside the update form, where there were all the other fields, this way PHP expected Ajax had all the data regarding all the mandatory fields.

I set up a new controller indipendent from the update fields and everything worked